# add a tall image to a bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a nasty little problem I can't solve. I need to add an tall image to a bootstrap navbar (navbar-fixed-top, if possible). The image is in the navbar-brand. Let's say that the image is 350px high, and the navbar 60px. That causes the background of the navbar to fill the space to the bottom of the image.

I need that image to stick out of the navbar and to have to text under it flow around it. If I use an absolute position for the image, it will be where I want it, but it will lay on top of the text. That's not good. I need the text to float around it.

How do I solve this one?

Comment: Please post your html & css, or a fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user/josflachs/fiddles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, or why you'd want to do this exactly, but this is my take on it:

I'd put the image in the body of the page, unless there's good reason to leave it in the header? This allows you to set properties for the surrounding text more effectively.

One note - the image you're using is a complete raster image, therefore, text won't wrap around the exterior of it like print layout will in an inline image in a magazine or newspaper for example. So if that's what you're looking for, you'd need to start with different image assets. 
I chose to address this question as if you wanted the text to wrap around the image rectangle only.

Also, I abandoned your css, and commented out two calls in the body to js files I didn't have locally, so that could impact the outcome.

Final note - because this image overlaps the header, I'd recommend doing something like a "pull-right" on the navbar so it doesn't get overlapped by the logo image.

The following HTML should be all you need to see the results - I'm just grabbing jQuery and Bootstrap from CDNs, should work for you as well. Let me know if you have any questions on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
    .navbar-brand {
        position: relative;
        top: -130px;
        left: -60px;
        margin: 0 0 25px 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9 pull-right">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://www.bitballoon.com//images/posts/grunt-logo.png"></a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- col-xs-8 -->
        </div><!-- row -->
      </div>
      <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://www.bitballoon.com//images/posts/grunt-logo.png"></a>
      <h1>Navbar example</h1>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')

    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- not sure what this is... removing ..................
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug 
    ..... don't have this script, removing .................
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The image was just to show something. Your solution is elegant, and exactly what I was looking for. My clients wants a logo in the navbar, and that was for me difficult to solve. This will do the trick nicely.